# <!--[if IE]> doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, if-statement

I have some svg code that works in all browsers except IE. if i add this, it works in IE:

```html
<canvas width="1900" height="1325" style="display:block;width:100%;visibility:hidden;"></canvas>
```

but it then messes up some stuff in all the other browsers. thus i tried to add this condition:

```html
<!--[if IE]><canvas width="1900" height="1325" style="display:block;width:100%;visibility:hidden;"></canvas><![endif]-->
```

but then again it works in all browsers except IE, thus i think IE is treating it as a comment.

i can't figure out what's wrong, any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Your `if [IE]` tag is utilised correctly; it will only execute inside Internet Explorer.

Comment: that's what i thought too, but it doesn't.

Comment: i mean it doesn't seem to execute in IE.

Comment: `<!--[if IE]>` only works in IE up to IE9 apparently - 10 and 11 treat it like it should be treated, a comment

Comment: right, so i'd have to target specifically? like <!--[if IE 11]>

Comment: no, you'd have to be running (or emulating) IE9 or earlier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<!--[if ????]>` only works in IE up to IE9.

IE10/11 treat it like it should be treated, a comment

to verify, open the developer tools in IE11

set IE to emulate "IE9" - and you'll see the conditional markup will be visible

switch back to 10/11 mode, and the content will again disappear

> **Important**  As of Internet Explorer 10, conditional comments are no longer supported by standards mode. Use feature detection to provide effective fallback strategies for website features that aren't supported by the browser. [source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=vs.85).aspx)